# why the syntax of some javaScript constructs is not defined in the ECMAScript specification

Tags: javascript, syntax, defined, ecmascript-2020

**Why the syntax of some javaScript contructs are not defined in ECMAScript specifications**

*for example the syntax of the if-statement in [ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-if-statement) is defined like*

```
13.6 The if Statement

Syntax

   IfStatement[Yield, Await, Return]:
   if ( Expression[+In, ?Yield, ?Await] ) Statement[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return] else
     Statement[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return]

   if( Expression[+In, ?Yield, ?Await] ) Statement[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return]

Each else for which the choice of associated if is ambiguous shall be associated with the nearest
possible if that would otherwise have no corresponding else.
```

*i need to know why in some constructs like the `for-statement`, `do-while statement` and the `while-statement` ECMAScript have not defined the syntax*

[if you search this ECMAScript specification **for the syntax of the for-statement you will not find**](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-for-statement)

[if you search this ECMAScript specification **for the syntax of the while-statement you will not find**](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-while-statement)

Comment: [Here it is](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-IterationStatement). Just click the link in the production at the section you linked.

Comment: than you very much